# Save result to a new csv file instead of println Groovy

Tags: json, groovy, export-to-csv

How can I save result of groovy script to a new file? C:/temp/all1.csv. I want to parse json file to csv, script is working fine but I don't know how can I save result in a new file. Please help.

```
import groovy.json.*
import java.io.File
def json ='''
{
   "expand": "schema,names",
   "startAt": 0,
   "maxResults": 50,
   "total": 21,
   "issues":    [
            {
         "expand": "operations,versionedRepresentations",
         "id": "217580",
         "self": "issue/217580",
         "key": "ART-4070",
         "fields": {"summary": "#[ART] Pre.3 Verification \\"S\\""}
      },
            {
         "expand": "operations,versionedRepresentations",
         "id": "217579",
         "self": "issue/217579",
         "key": "ART-4069",
         "fields": {"summary": "Verification \\"C\\""}
      },
            {
         "expand": "operations,versionedRepresentations",
         "id": "217577",
         "self": "issue/217577",
         "key": "ART-4068",
         "fields": {"summary": "#[ART] Enum type"}
      }
   ]
}
'''
File csvFile = new File( 'C:/temp/all1.csv')

def jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper()
def config = [ // header -> extractor
    "key": { it.key },
    "summary": { it.fields.summary }
]

def encode(e) { // help with nulls; quote the separator
    (e ?: "").replaceAll(";", "\\;")  
}

def csvLine(items) { // write items as "CSV"
  println(items.collect{ encode it }.join(";"))
}

def obj = new JsonSlurper().parseText(json)
csvLine(config.keySet())
obj.issues.each{ issue ->
    csvLine(config.values().collect{ f -> f issue })
}
```

result:
key;summary
ART-4070;#[ART] Pre.3 Verification "S"
ART-4069;Verification "C"
ART-4068;#[ART] Enum type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To go with the current code, you could use `csvFile.append(...)` instead of `println` inside your
`csvLine` function and depending on your amount of real data, this might
be a good compromise between performance and resource.

Or you can write the whole CSV at once.  E.g.

```
// prepare whole table
def data = [config.keySet()]
data.addAll(
    obj.issues.collect{ issue ->
        config.values().collect{ f -> f issue }
    }
)
// write table as csv
def csvFile = "/tmp/out.csv" as File
csvFile.text = data.collect{
    it.collect{ encode it }.join(";")9
}.join("\n")
```

Comment: def csvLine(items) { // write items as "CSV"  
 csvFile.append(  
    (items.collect{ encode it }.join(";"))  
 )  
}  ? No such property: csvFile for class